# How to remove d: from json response through c#?

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, asmx

I am consuming asmx web service from Visual studio c#. Sample code

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(WholeURL);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;


using (StreamWriter requester = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
requester.Write(postData);
requester.Close();
}

//Get the response
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.ok
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

How can i remove d from json response

my json response is :  { "d" : -1}
i only need -1.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change the server so it only gives you `-1` or are you trying to change the client so it knows how to parse the response properly? If you're trying to change the server, let's see what the code looks like on the server - a normal .asmx returns a SOAP message, not JSON, so we'd need to know how you're currently sending the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to parse the JSON, and grab the value at key="d".

Using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm)

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(values.Count);    // 2
Console.WriteLine(values["key1"]);  // value1
```